# Does there exist $\mathbf{Q} \subset R \subset \mathbf{C}$, $R$ ring & not field

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

I am looking for an example of a field extension $k \subset F$ and a unital ring $R$ that is not a field such that

$$k \subset R \subset F.$$

I know if $F$ is algebraic over $k$, then this is not possible.

I am interested if it is possible with $k = \mathbf{Q}$ and $F = \mathbf{C}$.

Comment: There is an injective map from $\mathbb Q[x]\to\mathbb R$ taking $x$ to $\pi$. Call the image of this map whatever you like — but that's an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's plenty of rings with those properties, because $\mathbb{C}$ has transcendency degree $2^{\aleph_0}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, so if you take any non empty subset $S$ of a transcendency basis, the ring $\mathbb{Q}[S]$ is not a field and is properly contained in $\mathbb{C}$; different subsets define different rings. So there are at least $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ rings like you require.

Not more, because that's the cardinality of the power set of $\mathbb{C}$, but of course those rings are not the whole set.

If you want *one* example, take any transcendental complex number $t$ and form the  ring $\mathbb{Q}[t]$.